# Switch to another desktop faster on macos high sierra

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, desktop, ui

On a macbook with macos high sierra, how do I switch between desktops faster by sliding 3 fingers across the touch pad?

Currently it takes ~1 second to switch to another screen. It does not matter if I slide the fingers or use Control+arrow, it takes the exact same time. I would like to make it faster. During the transition I can still type on the screen that I am switching from. I would like to make the transition faster or instantaneous, or at least make it so that I immediately start typing on the screen that I'm switching TO.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Your question is difficult to understand.  Are you asking how to switch Spaces faster than using a 3-finger swipe?

Comment: It's faster if you use the key commands to go directly to the required Space - but that doesn't work for fullscreen apps.

Comment: @fsb I edited the question.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer to this question on macOS 11.1 Big Sur. Here's an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the animated Space transition effect and speed up switching by enabling Reduce motion under System Preferences → Accessibility → Display

[image]

However, this will have the side effect of turning off most user interface animations.

Comment: Meh, it makes no difference. It just replaces the animation with a different animation that's just as long.